# Construction of type III von Neumann algebras

Tags: operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

I saw a conclusion: type III von Neumann algebras can be obtained by means of generalized Hilbert algebras and weights.

Can anyone show me the concrete conatructions or recommending some reference books on type III von Neumann algebras.

Answer (score 0):

See chapter XII in *Takesaki, Masamichi*, Theory of operator algebras. II, Encyclopaedia of Mathematical Sciences 125. Operator Algebras and Non-commutative Geometry 6. Berlin: Springer (ISBN 3-540-42914-X/hbk). xxii, 518 p. (2003). [ZBL1059.46031](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1059.46031).